# Use SqlServer HASHBYTES in EF Core Fluent Configuration

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to use HASHBYTES as the default value for a column in Entity Framework Core? On insert/update I would like to get the hash of the value in a different column in the same table.

In my configuration file I have something like this:

```
        builder.Property( a => a.File )
            .IsRequired();
        builder.Property(a => a.Hash)
            .HasDefaultValueSql( "HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', ??? )" )
```

but I can't figure out how to reference the 'File' column. How can I reference 'File'?

I tried:

```
builder.Property( a => a.Hash )
                .HasDefaultValueSql( "HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', [File] )" );
```

but the result is

```
The name "File" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.
```

Comment: You can't. The error message is clear: you cannot base the default value for a column off of another column; default constraints only support constants. What you want here (probably) is a computed column, not a column with a default that can later be changed independently of the file name -- use `.HasComputedColumnSql` for that.

Comment: Okay, thanks I will look into .HasComputedColumnSql